# CakePHP use both foreignKey and conditions in hasMany

Tags: cakephp

Objective: Person can follow any other Person or Organization.

```
/**
 * PersonFollow schema:
    CREATE TABLE `person_follows` (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `person_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        `table_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        `table_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
        KEY `i_person_id` (`person_id`),
        KEY `i_table_id` (`table_id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
 */

class PersonFollow extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Person' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'person_id',
        ),
        'FollowPerson' => array(
            'className' => 'Person',
            'foreignKey' => 'table_id',
            //'conditions' => array('PersonFollow.table_name' => 'persons'), // tried this
        ),
        'FollowOrganization' => array(
            'className' => 'Organization',
            'foreignKey' => 'table_id',
            //'conditions' => array('PersonFollow.table_name' => 'organizations'), // tried this
        ),
    );
}

class Person extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Following' => array(
            'className' => 'PersonFollow',
            'dependent' => true,
        ),
        'Follower' => array(
            'className' =>'PersonFollow',
            'foreignKey' => 'table_id',
            'conditions' => array('Follower.table_name' => 'persons'),
            'dependent' => true
        ),
    );
}

class Organization extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Follower' => array(
            'className' =>'PersonFollow',
            'foreignKey' => 'table_id',
            'conditions' => array('Follower.table_name' => 'organizations'),
            'dependent' => true
            /* Tried this
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'finderQuery' => 'SELECT `PersonFollow`.*
                FROM `person_follows` as `PersonFollow`
                WHERE `PersonFollow`.`table_id` = {$__cakeForeignKey__$}
                AND `PersonFollow`.`table_name` = "organizations"',
            */
        )
    );
}

$following = $this->Person->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array('Following' => array('FollowPerson','FollowOrganization')),
    'conditions' => array('Person.id' => 1234),
));
```

Results for `$following` return all Following that match on table_id, and does not use table_name condition. I'm trying to get FollowOrganization where PersonFollow.table_name = 'organizations' and same for FollowPerson where PersonFollow.table_name = 'persons'. It appears `$hasMany` is only using the 'foreignKey' and not the 'conditions'. What am I missing?

Comment: You should use [HABTM](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm)

Comment: The person_follows table essentially is the join table. What would the db schema look like in your HABTM solution?